Identify short story about scientists spending every second of their lives learning only adding new info in their last days, looking for immortality
I'm looking for the name of a short story. It began with a representative of the King asking for help from his scientists or alchemists, or academics - the story uses a specific term, but I forgot which exactly.
Summary
Those studied persons were trying to find immortality (I believe), and the king's request is rejected with a long explanation about why none of the most educated can help.
Their very best need every second of their life to advance the boundaries of human knowledge, learning and studying all that already exists, only just barely adding to the canon of knowledge in the last hours of their life.
At the same time, the very best teachers need to spend all their efforts improving the the ability to teach, so that the scientists could learn faster and find new discoveries at the end of their lives.
As far as I recall, the King asked for help to cure a terminal illness of his son - or perhaps his wife, daughter, or himself? I am unsure.
Previous encounters with the story
I found the story online, either hosted on a website or as a pdf. This must have been around 10-15 years ago. The story was most likely in English, with a small chance of it being in German instead.
I can't recall much more about the context of seeing the story before. I think it's a fairly short read, on the order of 10 to, at most 60 minutes.
Any hints would be very appreciated!

What was the king's request? What did he want the scientists' help with?

Good point - while the answer was found, I still added it to maybe improve googleability.

Russian adaptation: https://youtu.be/7yXU5g4Dnqw

I'm pretty sure this is Ars Longa, Vita Brevis by Scott Alexander. The intelligentsia are known as alchemists, and here are the relevant quotes:

The first student has no master, and must discover everything himself. He researches for 70 years, then writes his wisdom into a book before he dies. The second student reads the book, and in 7 years, he has learned 70 years of research. Then he does his own original research for 63 years and writes a book containing 133 years of research. The third student reads for 13.3 years, then does his own research for 66.7 years, ending up with 200 years. Imagine going further and further. After many generations, 690 years of research have been done, and it takes a student 69 years to master them. The student only has one year left of life to research further, leaving the world with 691 years of research total. So the cycle creeps onward, always approaching but never quite reaching 700 years of architectural research.


“Do you remember the architects who learned at ten times the rate they researched, the ones who would never accumulate more than 700 years of learning? The fiftieth alchemist in the sequence has 696 years of learning, and is able to do a scant five months’ original research before his death. The hundredth alchemist has 699.98 years of learning, and is able to do about a day’s research before dying. We are not so far along as all that, but we are far. We do not have the Stone, but we have tinctures that can stabilize the lifespan, make sure nobody dies before their time. The last few generations – on their deathbed, they say they can almost taste the Stone, that it lies only a few hours of further thought beyond their level. They say of my grandfather that he realized the recipe for the Stone on his deathbed, that he started speaking it, but that his eyes closed forever before he could complete the ingredient list.”


That's the one, thanks so much!
